# cant get array to display text and pictures in php

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I'm trying to get elements from an array to display on the screen. How do I target the array elements?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
    html {
        background-color: bisque;
    }

    h1 {

        display: block;
        text-align: center;

    }

    h2 {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        color: saddlebrown;
    }

    img {
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 800px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    p {

        text-align: center;
        color: saddlebrown;
    }

</style>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dynamic web pages with PHP</title>

</head>


<body>
    <header>
        <nav id="main-navigation">

        </nav>
    </header>
    <h1>My favourite Car</h1>

    <?php 

    $cars = [
        [

            "name" => "HRV",
            "price" => "CAD-$23300",
            "src" => "http://direct.automobiles.honda.com/images/2016/hr-v/exterior-gallery-new/2016-honda-hrv-front-view.jpg",
            "description" => "HRV is a mini suv made by Honda."
         ],
             [
            "name" => "CHR",
            "price" =>"CAD-$23675",
            "src" => "https://d1bxbrgbmu84na.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/16093812/CHR.jpg",
            "description" => "CHR is a mini suv made by Toyota."
             ],
             [
            "name" => "RDX",
            "price" =>"CAD-$43990",
            "src" => "https://www.acura.ca/Content/acura.ca/e270f141-7f67-4fe2-99bd-e808e3c3c2d7/MediumSizedFeature/03_rdx19_overview_MediumFeature_mobile.jpg",
            "description" => "RDX is a large SUV made by Acura." 
             ]

            ];

                       foreach($cars as $car){ ?>

                <img src="<?php echo "$car->src" ?>">
                <h2><?php echo $car->name ?></h2>
                <p><?php echo $car->price ?></p>
                 <p><?php echo $car->description ?></p>
        <?php

    } 

 ?>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: I'm having difficulties understanding your question, so it it might be difficult for contributors of this site to actually help you. Here are a few hints to help you improve your question. Can you explain what's wrong with your current code? Do you have an error message? If so, what is that error? Is the result different form what you expect? Please show what you expect and what you get. Also, your code seems to be much more verbose that might be required to demonstrate your issue. For example, I don't think we need CSS rules. Can you please reduce it as much as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using object syntax but are working with an array.

Use the following syntax to access the array elements:

```
$car['src'];
$car['name'];
```

...etc